# Email merge field is empty when email is being sent from Community

Tags: email-template, administration, customer-community

I have Reset Password `email template` with merge fields. When I test it from the org (`clicking Send Test and Verify Merge Fields`) the fields are populated. It works fine.

But, when the community users reset their passwords the email comes with one empty merge field, which is Custom field on User obj. Other standard merge fields are populated.

Here is the template:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>{!$Label.TRAXEE_Hi} {!Receiving_User.FirstName},</p>
            <p>{!$Label.TRAXEE_Forgot_Password}? {!$Label.TRAXEE_Reset_Explanation}</p>
            <p><a href="{!Community_Url}" target="_blank">{!$Label.TRAXEE_Click_Here}</a> {!$Label.TRAXEE_Reset_Password}</p>
            <p>{!$Label.TRAXEE_Email_Address}: {!Receiving_User.Username} </p>
            <p>{!$Label.TRAXEE_BestRegards}<br>TRAXEE</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>WABCO TRAXEE</b><br /> {!Receiving_User.TRAXEE_Support__c} - <a href="http://www.wabco-traxee.com" target="_blank">www.wabco-traxee.com</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Custom field `{!Receiving_User.TRAXEE_Support__c}` is empty. And standard field `{!Receiving_User.Username}` is populated.

`TRAXEE_Support__c` is Editable for Community Profile.

Did anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: Check community user have sufficient Field Level Security on custom email field.

Comment: @RadheRadhe, I mentioned that Community Profile has FLS on that Custom field. The field is User. TRAXEE_Support__c.

Comment: There is one more post related to merge field that says to clone the template and refer new template wherever you want to use. Another post is  -  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75647/merge-field-not-populating-in-email-template

Comment: @RadheRadhe I tried, but it doesn`t do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving_User merge field is pulling fields from the Contact object.

['Receiving_User' merge field in Password Reset email in communities has no value](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231274&type=1)